# LoadModel Error,LoadQuery Error in korzh Easy Query query builder

Tags: easyquery

I am using Korzh Easy Query in my ASP.NET MVC project. Included the default easy query view in my views and its respective controller. When the page load i am getting a load model error. But when i remove the modelName parameter in the easy query settings i did'nt get any exceptions but the table names aren't listed in the left side panel.But everything works fine in the sample demo project provided by easy query. For model loading i am using the xml file generated from the data model editor for my database.

The error that i am getting are

> LoadModel Error-> When the page loads
>
> LoadQuery Error -> when clicking load query button
>
> SaveQuery Error -> When clicking save query button

Answer (score 1):

1. What exactly that "Load Model" error message says?
2. Did you place your model XML file into App_Data folder?
3. Why don't you contact support?

Comment: I've already contacted them..Still no reply...The loadModel error says 404 not found in the alert box in IE 11. The model XML is in the app_data folder only.

Comment: How did you contacted support? There is a contact/support form on the web-site: http://devtools.korzh.com/support/

Comment: As for 404 error - it seems you didn't define EasyQueryController correctly so GetModel action is not found when EasyQuery widgets send their AJAX call.